# Sequence translation mapping proper nouns to entity types

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, machine-translation

I'm trying to perform a sequence to sequence translation with biological scientific text which has a LOT of proper nouns in it into a structured language for biology. I can pretty easily tag the terms (proteins, chemical compounds, etc) with their entity types.

I was wondering if there is a way to replace the nouns with their entity types (in a way that would let me match and add them back after translation) or annotate them in a way that would enhance the translation process.

For example, converting "Simvastatin-induced apoptosis is accompanied by specific induction of caveolin-1 expression" to "simvastin increases rna expression of caveolin-1"  - simvastin == compound, caveolin-1 == RNA

My expectation is that I would need less training data if I could pre-process the input sentences, but only if I can convert " induced apoptosis is accompanied by specific induction of  expression" in a way that I can match up the original entities in the output (easy with one entity of each type, but what happens if I have multiple compounds or RNA's?).

Comment: I was thinking about using Noun Chunks, but with deeper reasoning it became clear that you have some deep problems there: if you just reserve these proteins names, bacteria and characteristics and translate verbs, adverbs and so on, you will end up with unintelligible entries for languages that have a different syntactical structure when compared to english. Just as an example: in portuguese, adjectives usually come after the noun (so, "Simvastatin-induced apoptosis" would become "apoptosis simvastatin-induced"). What are your target languages? What have you gotten so far?

Comment: Planning to translate into BEL - a structured language for biology that is computable and formalized - kind of like a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea seems reasonable. A similar approach was successfully used for the translation of noisy texts where they used [placeholders for emoticons](http://www.statmt.org/wmt19/pdf/53/WMT61.pdf).

There is a project called [scispacy](https://allenai.github.io/scispacy/),  a Python package containing spaCy models for processing biomedical, scientific or clinical text. Standard named-entity recognition would not find anything.

It should be able to detect the biomedical entities. You can install it by:

```sh
pip install spacy scispacy https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-s2-scispacy/releases/v0.2.3/en_core_sci_sm-0.2.3.tar.gz
```

```
In [1]: import scispacy 
   ...: import spacy 
   ...:  
   ...: nlp = spacy.load("en_core_sci_sm")

In [2]: doc = nlp("Simvastatin-induced apoptosis is accompanied by specific induction of caveolin-1 expression.")                                                                      

In [3]: doc.ents                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[3]: (Simvastatin-induced apoptosis, induction, caveolin-1, expression)
```

The outputs might be even better if you use other models that are available, maybe they get better results. Based on that, you can try to come up with some based on the detected entites.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Scispacy looks interesting. I'm not too worried about doing the NER, I'm more worried about the training data required to translate biological text into a programming like format (BEL). That is why I was wondering if there was a placeholder approach that would work for a Seq2Seq translation model.

Comment: I'm following up with the authors of the placeholders for emoticons authors to find out more about how they did that. That's exactly the approach I'm looking for. Thanks!